# Installed kernel not in /boot

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-esxi, grub2

I have a LAMP configured Ubuntu 10.04 LTS VM on my ESXi server.

I've installed the "Virtual" kernel but only the original "Server" kernel is available at boot. `ls /boot` only shows files associated with the current and previous "Server" kernels, not the "Virtual" one.

Aptitude is convinced the virtual version is installed (it shows up with the "i" status in `search` and reinstalling doesn't change anything). I've run `update-grub` (and `update-grub2`), without luck (although I believe they only process kernels already in `/boot`).

I thought (i.e. I think previously when I've done this) that installing a new kernel type added entries in /boot and that grub would then allow booting into that kernel.

Have I missed a step? What can I do?

Comment: What are you talking about?  What do you mean by 'virtual' kernel?  What is the package name, or if it isn't an Ubuntu package, then where did you download it from?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, Zordache - I'm talking about the meta-package "Linux-image-virtual" in the main Ubuntu repo. I didn't think this would be particularly obscure for anyone looking at a question tagged "VMware".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vmlinuz images for the `-virtual` kernels stopped being named `virtual` a while ago (even though the package still is). In Ubuntu Lucid i386 they are named `generic-pae`, in amd64 they are named `server`.

amd64:

```
% apt-file list linux-image-2.6.32-37-virtual | grep vmlinuz
linux-image-2.6.32-37-virtual: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-37-server
```

i386:

```
% apt-file list linux-image-2.6.32-37-virtual | grep vmlinuz
linux-image-2.6.32-37-virtual: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-37-generic-pae
```

You can find the exact file installed by a package using `dpkg -L`:

```
% dpkg -L linux-image-2.6.32-41-virtual | grep vmlinuz
/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-41-generic-pae
```

Comment: Thanks mgorven - that's the answer. It never occurred to me that the kernel I was trying to get would have been renamed in the same form as the one I was trying to replace! I hadn't realised the "virtual" suffix had been dropped.